# How to create Primary Index for password protected buckets in Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view, nosql

I have a bucket name user-account with password 'user' 
and I am trying to create Primary Index on this bucket

```
 CREATE PRIMARY INDEX ON `user-account`
```

but its giving

```
{
"requestID": "83e90d2d-18dc-4eb7-af34-7d689d962c8a",
"signature": null,
"results": [
],
"errors": [
    {
        "code": 13000,
        "msg": "Failed to create view #primary - cause: error installing view: 401 Unauthorized / {\"error\":\"unauthorized\",\"reason\":\"password required\"}\n"
    }
],
"status": "errors",
"metrics": {
    "elapsedTime": "15.466089ms",
    "executionTime": "15.260122ms",
    "resultCount": 0,
    "resultSize": 0,
    "errorCount": 1
}
}
```

If I remove the password then that same code is working.

Can anyone suggest me any solution for this..
Any help will be appreciated..!!!

Comment: What versions of couchbase?

Comment: Couchbase Server 4.0 — BETA

Comment: Are you using the CBQ client or one of the RESTful APIs?

Comment: Looks like a known [bug](http://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-15408)